# Why does pandas.DataFrame.apply return identical rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does this code produces a DF with three identical rows?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
print(df.apply(lambda s: [s], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    [[3, z]]
1    [[3, z]]
2    [[3, z]]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a bug in pandas. I opened a bug report, we'll see what pandas devs think.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54250

Regarding @mozway answer, I can just repeat my comment: In python, returning [] or [s] creates a new list every time the function is called. For example,

```
def g():
  return []
assert g() is not g()
```

I don't see any reason that Pandas should break this behavior.

Comment: it's not a bug, but a consequence of some optimization of `apply`. Just make a copy of `s` inside `lambda`.

Comment: @Vitalizzare What do you mean it's not a bug? It's not a documented behavior of `apply`, nor is it a python standard behavior. So what makes it not a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're reusing the same list object, so the last value is being used.

```
# the same list is reused
print(df.apply(lambda s: id([]), axis=1))
0    140024867672128
1    140024867672128
2    140024867672128
dtype: int64

# if we use "list" a new list is generated
print(df.apply(lambda s: id(list()), axis=1))
0    140024867678528
1    140024867670848
2    140024867673600
dtype: int64
```

Use instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z']})

print(df.apply(list, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    [1, x]
1    [2, y]
2    [3, z]
dtype: object
```

Vectorial alternative:

```
out = pd.Series(df.to_numpy().tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
0    [1, x]
1    [2, y]
2    [3, z]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Returning [] or [s] creates a new list every time the function is called. For example `def g():  return []; assert g() is not g()`. How does pandas manage to break this behavior? And how is it not considered a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you suggest, i.e. `df.apply(list, axis=1)`, does not output a list with a sequence inside as an element of this list. It's the same as `df.apply(lambda s: [*s], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

As [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76759647/19060733) mentioned, I am adding an improved answer that is more time efficient -

```
[list(x) for x in df.values]
```

The timings for each would be -

```
%timeit -r 7 -n 10000 df.apply(list, axis=1)
164 µs ± 5.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

**AND**

```
%timeit -r 7 -n 10000 [list(x) for x in df.values]
17.1 µs ± 162 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. Still, my question was about *why* this happens. Your answer provides a useful a workaround, but before applying the workaround, I'd like to understand what's going on in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to add more to the *reasoning* , just  met with a same problem and thought might share a workaround that was more time efficient in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all the previous answers are not correct. The obtained lists are different, but the object inside of them is the same. Try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
for seq in df.apply(lambda s: [s], axis=1):
    print(f'{id(seq)=}, {id(seq[0])=}, {type(seq[0])=}')
```

[image: check object id]

You need to make a copy of `s` inside of your lambda function:

```
print(df.apply(lambda s: [s.copy()], axis=1))
```

[image: making a copy of a row in apply]